# Angular (not the angularjs) + JAVA?

Tags: java, angular

I would like to know if it is possible to create a project which use ANGULAR (not ANGULARJS) and JAVA ? If it is possible :

- Is it only Angular (front) and angular (back) ?
- Can it be realised with only one project which is launched on a server ?
- Is it often used in the companies ?

Comment: You can only use Angular for the front end if you want and anything else for the back end (REST API).

Comment: angular is written in javascript and its sole purpose is the easy creation of UIs so you don't need to use it in the backend. If you want to use JS for the backend you could have a look at a node-server

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am sorry, i made a mistake. I wanted to know if it is ANGULAR in front end and JAVA in back end. I guess, it is SPRING RESTCONTROLLERS which must be used in the back end. Please, can you confirm it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

lets answer your questions one by one:

1) Angular is a front end technology, build on top of **TypeScript** which after build converts into **JavaScript**.

2) Here, I guess you want to know how to deploy it ? You can bundle your app along with Java back end or you can bundle them separately and deploy.

3) There are many companies which uses Angular as a front end and Java (Spring/Spring Boot) as a back end.